# 403 forbidden access apache on ubuntu full access

Tags: 12.04, server, apache2

we had an issue with our sites on our Ubuntu server.

basically we did a `chmod -R 777` on the `var` folder to grant full permissions. Is that ok to do?

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 ftpuser ecoftpgroup   30 2011-06-03 15:37 mywebsite.co.uk -> /var/www/clients/client5/web6/
```

How can i also find info about the user and group as stated in the line above?

It was working fine yesterday and today we got the 403 forbidden error.

Comment: `we did a chmod -R 777 on the var folder` I'm pretty sure that's bad unless you meant the `/var/www` folder

Comment: Yes sorry the var/www folder

Answer (score 0):

Check the permission of parent folders. All the folders in the chain must have +x (execute privileges) available to the www-data user (usually via other permission).

Comment: Thanks will check that. I was thinking of changing the users to www-data along with the group using chown